# is it possible to call an executable file and give it variables in a fortran code?

Tags: fortran

I would like to call an executable file and give it variables in my fortran code. 
for example:

```
function obj(ii)
use omp_lib
use  ifport
implicit none
integer,intent(in)::ii
integer::     thron
real::obj
thron=omp_get_thread_num()
obj=RUNQQ('C:\pgi\matlab_omp_cuda\test.exe','')
return
end function  obj
```

In this code, "thron" is the thread no. which is a variable in another executable file.

Comment: MSB's solution is good, if the passed variables are simple, otherwise you will need data file on disk. However be careful with using functions for this. A subroutine is clearer and there are subtle dangers with sideeffects in functions. Fortran is not C.

Answer (score 2):

Fortran 2008 provides the intrinsic subroutine `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE` which will allow you to invoke an executable file.  You could pass options on the command line.  If the executable was created from Fortran, in the Fortran source you could read options on the the command line with the intrinsics `COMMAND_ARGUMENT_COUNT` and `GET_COMMAND_ARGUMENT`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but could you plz give me an example? Thanks again.

Comment: There are examples in the gfortran manual.  Please try based on those examples and if it still doesn't work, ask a question, showing your code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I know how to use it.